# Why does Unexpected implicit cast to `EditText`: layout tag was `TextView`

Tags: android-studio, android-implicit-intent

I have a problem, I'm trying to finish the lesson Android fundamentals 02.3: Implicit intents, but there are some errors

the first one is Unexpected implicit cast to `EditText`: layout tag was `TextView`

the second one is Consider adding a  declaration to your manifest when calling this \ method; see https://g.co/dev/packagevisibility for details

when running the application, it automatically stops immediately, I have tried it on the emulator and on real devices

source codelab : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-activity-with-implicit-intent?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0

Code MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.implicitintents;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mWebsiteEditText;
    private EditText mLocationEditText;
    private EditText mShareTextEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebsiteEditText = findViewById(R.id.website_edittext);
        mLocationEditText = findViewById(R.id.location_edittext);
        mShareTextEditText = findViewById(R.id.share_edittext);
    }

    public void openWebsite(View view) {
        String url = mWebsiteEditText.getText().toString();

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d("ImplicitIntents", "Can't handle this intent!");
        }
    }

    public void openLocation(View view) {
        String loc = mLocationEditText.getText().toString();

        Uri addressUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + loc);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, addressUri);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d("ImplicitIntents", "Can't handle this intent!");
        }
    }

    public void shareText(View view) {
        String txt = mShareTextEditText.getText().toString();
        String mimeType = "text/plain";
        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                .from(this)
                .setType(mimeType)
                .setChooserTitle("Share this text with: ")
                .setText(txt)
                .startChooser();
    }
}
```

Code Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/website_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_uri" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_website_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="openWebsite"
        android:text="@string/button_uri" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_loc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_location_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="openLocation"
        android:text="@string/button_loc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/share_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_share" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share_text_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="shareText"
        android:text="@string/button_share" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot the error code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file you declare three elements as Textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/website_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_uri" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_loc" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/share_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edittext_share" />
```

And then in your activity you declare your variables as EditText

```
 private EditText mWebsiteEditText;
 private EditText mLocationEditText;
 private EditText mShareTextEditText;
```

And that's why your seeing those errors of casting.

Change in your xml file to EditText if you want to input some data or leave it like TextView if you want display some text but change the type of your variables in the activity. Make sure both are the same type

Comment: oh my god, what am i doing, thankss man, really helpful

Comment: Glad to help :). Try to help me back selecting the answer as the one that worked for you or voting up.